# socket programming for transferring a photo in python

Tags: python, sockets, file-transfer

I'm new to socket programming in python. Here is an example of opening a TCP socket in a Mininet host and sending a photo from one host to another. In fact I have changed the code which I used to send a simple message to another host ([writing the received data to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265502/writing-the-received-data-to-a-text-file)) in order to meet my requirements. 
But when I run this code, I encounter this error at sender side:

```
144
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File mmyClient2,pym, line 13, in <module> 
    if(s.sendall(data)):
  File m/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pym, line 228, in meth
    return yetattr[self,_sockename](*args) 
  File m/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pym, line 174, in _dummy 
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor') 
socket,error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

So what's wrong?

Receiver.py

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('10.0.0.1', 12345))

buf = 1024
f = open("2.jpg",'wb')

s.listen(1)
conn , addr = s.accept()
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(buf)
    print(data[:10])
    #print "PACKAGE RECEIVED..."
    f.write(data)   
    if not data: break
    #conn.send(data)
conn.close()
s.close()
```

Sender.py:

```
import socket
import sys

f=open ("1.jpg", "rb")
print sys.getsizeof(f)
buf = 1024
data = f.read(buf)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('10.0.0.1',12345))

while (data):
    if(s.sendall(data)):
        #print "sending ..."
        data = f.read(buf)
        #print(f.tell(), data[:10])
s.close()
```

There seems to be a problem with s.sendall(), because when I change it to s.send(), there is no error and photo transfer is successful. So my question is: Although I was suggested to use s.sendall() instead of s.send() in my previous question on this site, Is it wrong not to do this?

Comment: Most likely the exception is raised because you called `s.close()` on the socket, and then tried to call `s.sendall()` on the now-closed socket in the next iteration of your while-loop.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Which s.close() you mean? the one that is in the else condition? I removed it. Although the error disappeared, I have an infinite loop in receiver.py which prints .adobe.com ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After send all data, you closed socket.And use closed socket again, that cause error.You can write sender like this.

```
import socket
import sys

f=open ("1.jpg", "rb")
print sys.getsizeof(f)
buf = 1024
data = f.read(buf)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('10.0.0.1',12345))

while 1:
    if not data:
        break
    s.sendall(data)
    data = f.read(buf)
s.close()
```

Comment: Ok, I replaced `s.close()` with `break`. But there is still problem and my photo is not transferred correctly. Only when I change `s.sendall()` to `s.send()`, this photo transfer seems to be correct. However, in my previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274595/python-socket-programming-for-transferring-a-photo), In order for my transfer to take place correctly and completely, I should use `sendall()` instead of `send()`... But as you see when I do this, I encounter an error or infinite loop

Comment: @helen Try the new one.That works for me in fedora os.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the `s.sendall()` problem. But when I run these 2 codes, a 144 appears in output of sender.py (As it was there in my first error too) . What is it and why is it happening?

Comment: 144 is length of file. `print sys.getsizeof(f)`